# Corenlp basic errors

Tags: stanford-nlp

Take the phrase "A Pedestrian wishes to cross the road".

I learnt english in England and, according to the old rules, the word 'Pedestrian' is a noun.  Stanford CoreNLP finds it  to be an adjective, regardless of capitalization.

I don't want to contradict the big-brains of Stanford, USA, but that is just wrong.  I am new to this semantic stuff but, by finding the word to be an adjective, the sentence lacks a valid noun phrase.

Have I missed the point of CoreNLP, lost the point of the english language, or should I be seeking more effective analysis tools?

I ask as the example sentence is the very first sentence, of my very first processing experiment, and it is most discouraging.

Answer (score 0):

CoreNLP is a statistical analysis tool. It is trained on many texts that have been annotated by pools of human experts. These experts agree on about 90% of the cases. Thus the CoreNLP system cannot beat that percentage and your sentence is part of the 10% wrong parses.